# Error mostrado por Google Play: "The vulnerabilities were addressed in OpenSSL 1.0.2f/1.0.1r"

Tags: android, google-play, openssl

Estoy intentando subir mi aplicación a play store, pero recibí el siguiente error:

> "OpenSSL The vulnerabilities were addressed in OpenSSL 1.0.2f/1.0.1r.
>   To confirm your OpenSSL version, you can do a grep search for: \$
>   unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL"

Quería ver si alguien ha pasado por el mismo error y cómo resolverlo, ya que buscando en internet no he encontrado la solución actualmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te traduzco lo que indica la [documentación de Google](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6376725?hl=en) sobre este error:

### ¿Cómo hacer frente a las vulnerabilidades de OpenSSL en sus aplicaciones?

Esta información está destinada a desarrolladores de aplicaciones con enlaces estáticos hacia versiones OpenSSL precedentes a 1.0.2f/1.0.1r. Estas versiones contienen vulnerabilidades de seguridad.

**Por favor migrar su aplicación a OpenSSL 1.0.2f/1.0.1r o superior tan pronto como sea posible e incremente el número de versión del archivo APK actualizado.** **A partir del 11 de julio de 2016**, Google Play bloqueará la publicación de nuevas aplicaciones o actualizaciones que utilizan versiones anteriores de OpenSSL. Su versión de la aplicación publicada no se verán afectados, sin embargo se bloquearán las actualizaciones de la aplicación a menos que no se dirijan a esta vulnerabilidad.

**Próximos pasos:**

1. Migrar su aplicación a OpenSSL 1.0.2f / 1.0.1r o superior e incrementar el número de versión.
2. Inicie sesión en su consola de desarrollador y presente la versión actualizada de su aplicación.
3. Compruebe de nuevo después de cinco horas - vamos a mostrar un mensaje de advertencia si la aplicación no se ha actualizado correctamente.

Las vulnerabilidades se abordaron en OpenSSL 1.0.2f / 1.0.1r. Las últimas versiones de OpenSSL [se pueden descargar aquí](https://www.openssl.org/source/). Para confirmar la versión de OpenSSL, puede hacer una búsqueda por (`$ unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL"`).

Si está utilizando una biblioteca de terceros que usa OpenSSL, tendrá que actualizar su biblioteca a una versión que use OpenSSL 1.0.2f / 1.0.1r o superior.

Las vulnerabilidades incluyen "[callejón sin salida](https://weakdh.org/)" (logjam)  y [CVE-2015-3194](http://arstechnica.com/security/2016/01/high-severity-bug-in-openssl-allows-attackers-to-decrypt-https-traffic/). El ataque logjam permite que un atacante man-in-the-middle pueda rebajar las conexiones TLS vulnerables a la criptografía de exportación de grado de 512 bits. Esto permite al atacante leer y modificar todos los datos que pasan a través de la conexión. Los detalles sobre otras vulnerabilidades están disponibles [aquí](https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv/20160128.txt). Para otras preguntas técnicas, puede preguntar en [Stackoverflow](https://www.es.stackoverflow.com/questions) usando las etiquetas de "android-seguridad" y "OpenSSL".

Si bien estos problemas no afecten a todas las aplicaciones que utilizan las versiones de OpenSSL anteriores 1.0.2f / 1.0.1r, lo mejor es mantenerse al tanto de todos los parches de seguridad. Aplicaciones con vulnerabilidades que exponen a los usuarios a riesgo de compromiso puede ser considerado en violación de nuestras [políticas  sobre Comportamiento malicioso](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-and-security.html#malicious-behavior) y la [sección 4.4](https://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html#prohibited) del Acuerdo de distribución.

Antes de publicar aplicaciones, por favor asegúrese de que son compatibles con el [Acuerdo de distribución](https://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html) y [Política de contenido](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html). Si usted siente que le hemos enviado un aviso OpenSSL por error, póngase en contacto con nuestro equipo de soporte a través del [Centro de asistencia para desarrolladores de Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/publishing).